# Joining Columns From different tables, and to get the total of the joined columns

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have edited the question and this was the solution that worked,

```
SELECT yesterday.yesterday, today.today, report.id, report.balance, 
    report.debit, report.credit, cumulative.cumulative, report.name
   FROM ( SELECT y.balance AS yesterday
           FROM report_account_receivable_yesterday) yesterday, 
    ( SELECT t.balance AS today
           FROM report_account_receivable_today) today, 
    ( SELECT sum(y.balance + t.balance) AS cumulative
           FROM report_account_receivable_yesterday y, 
            report_account_receivable_today t) cumulative, 
    ( SELECT min(l.id) AS id, 
            to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
            sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, 
            sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day' AS tarehe
           FROM account_move_line l
      LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
     WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text AND l.date = DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day'
     GROUP BY to_char(l.date:
```

:timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type) report
  ORDER BY report.id DESC;

the problem is with getting data for previous day using `DATE 'now()' - interval '1 day'` as it will give me this output in the query in my view

```
sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type, '2013-12-16'::date AS tarehe
   FROM account_move_line l
   LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id
  WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text AND l.date = '2013-12-16'::date
```

Comment: You should really format the query so it is more readable and learn to use modern `join` syntax.  The `,`s should be replaced with `cross join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT yesterday, today 
FROM 
   (SELECT report_account_receivable_yesterday.balance AS yesterday 
   FROM report_account_receivable_yesterday) yesterday,

   (SELECT report_account_receivable_today.balance AS today 
   FROM report_account_receivable_today) today, 

   (SELECT id, name, balance, debit, credit, a.type 
   FROM 
      (SELECT min(l.id) AS id, to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text) AS name, 
         sum(l.debit - l.credit) AS balance, sum(l.debit) AS debit, sum(l.credit) AS credit, a.type 
      FROM account_move_line l) AS id
   ) ssssssssssssssssssssssssss 

   LEFT JOIN account_account a ON l.account_id = a.id

WHERE l.state::text <> 'draft'::text
GROUP BY to_char(l.date::timestamp with time zone, 'YYYY:IW'::text), a.type;
```

I think you missing alias at "ssssssssssssssssssssssssss"

Comment: Thanks Kamonwat, the problem i have now is the timestamp. i want to get data for previous date, i know i can use DATE 'now()' - INTERVAL '1 day' but the problem is if i use it in my query it gives '2013-02-16'::date and it stays that way,, i want it to be changing in such a way that if todays date is 20th it should read '2013-12-19'::date and not '2013-12-16'::date in the query in my view